# phpMyAdmin No Login Screen

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I am working on building my first ever database on my home computer using mysql. The intent is to use mysql and phpMyAdmin together with Apache to create and serve my database (for a school project). Several days ago I had all the software configured and running properly, but had not begun to build my database. When I returned to work on it today, I am unable to produce a login screen from phpMyAdmin.

I have verified that Apache is running by checking my http://localhost page, as well as verifying php functionality through the phpinfo file. Both tests were successful. Despite that, when navigating to 
localhost/~(myhome)/phpmyadmin/ 
it only produces a blank page, whereas two days ago there was a login screen. I attempted a reinstall of the phpmyadmin resources, and arrived at the same problem.

I have mysql installed and accessible from the command line on my Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4. The MYSQL version is 8.0.11, and was installed using HomeBrew. Any info on how I can resolve this issue is appreciated.

This is my first post on this site, so please forgive me if I am missing any essential information/formatting.

EDIT:
At the suggestion of my professor I deleted the config.inc.php entirely from the phpmyadmin directory and ran the setup process over again, and generated a new config file. This solved my issue.

Comment: you must post any error or code to solve your problem.

Comment: The problem I am experiencing produces no error. Merely a blank page. If there is something specific anyone would need to see I can pull it up but I'm unsure as to what portion of what file would be relevant in the php configuration.

Comment: Please check console for errors in the inspect window, if there was an error, add it to your question.

Comment: Are you using wamp?

Comment: Amir- I checked the console and there are no errors. The inspect window shows me a completely blank html document.

Bleach- I am not using wamp.

Answer (score 0):

At the suggestion of my professor I deleted config.inc.php entirely from the phpmyadmin directory and ran the setup process over again, and generated a new config file. This solved my issue.